# View won't disappear from iPad, but works fine on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

UDPATED WITH FIRST SUGGESTION BELOW, STILL EXPERIENCING ISSUE: I inherited some iPhone apps from a developer, and now I'm the developer with very few skills. I'm trying to convert one of these iPhone apps to universal (iPhone & iPad), and I'm nearly there, just one issue: I have a view that correctly disappears on the iPhone, but not on the iPad. Hoping someone here can help me, I've been struggling with this one issue (which hopefully has a fairly simple solution) for 3+ days, and I think I've pulled all my hair out. :)

I've been told some of this is old code, and that may be true, but because this one issue is blocking me from submitting to the app store, I'd rather avoid big refactoring/redesign solutions for now. So here's what's going on (apologies in advance for the funky formatting on this post, not sure why code isn't all going in the coding format, funky bullet numbering, etc):

1. App starts from my main view controller (MyAppViewController), which has a "Play" button which starts gameplay. When the "Play button is tapped, the following code instantiates the gameplay view controller:

   mainGameViewControllerIpad = [[MainGameViewControllerIpad alloc]
                                 initWithNibName:nil
                                 bundle:nil];
   [self.view addSubview:mainGameViewControllerIpad.view];

This opens up the view MainGameViewControllerIpad, and the user plays the game.

1. Once the game round ends, the code in MainGameViewControllerIpad does this:

   GameStatsViewControllerIpad *gameStatsViewControllerIpad = [[GameStatsViewControllerIpad alloc] init];
   [gameStatsViewControllerIpad setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
   [self presentModalViewController:gameStatsViewControllerIpad animated:YES];

   [self.view addSubview:gameStatsViewControllerIpad.view];

   [gameStatsViewControllerIpad setStatsDisplay];

This opens up the Game Stats view, which tells the user how they did on the round they just played. So you have the intro screen view, then the gameplay view controller as a subview of that, and the stats screen as a subview of the gameplay view. This works fine on both iPhone and iPad.

So here's where things get weird:

1. When the user is done viewing their stats, they tap the "done" button on the stats page, and the following code runs:

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
[self.view release];

SO HERE'S THE ISSUE: on the iPhone, this closes the Stats view, and I'm assuming that because the stats view is a subview of the MainGameViewController, that view disappears as well, and the user is returned to the MyAppViewController. THIS IS CORRECT.

However, on the iPad, when the above code runs, it closes the immediate Stats view, but once it's gone, it reveals that the MainGameViewController view is still visible -- in other words, on the iPhone, the code above closes the subview and it's container view, but on the iPad, it doesn't close the parent/Super view.

Anyone have any fairly simple suggestions on how to get the MainGameViewController to also work on the iPad? Thanks in advance for any insight/suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Just dismiss the modal view rather than removing it.

```
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, DCGod! Just so I'm understanding, do you mean I should replace:

[self.view removeFromSuperview];

With this:

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Is that the suggestion? I tried it and when I clicked the "done" button on the stats page, the app screen went white, almost as if there's no viewControllers left on the screen at all. It almost seems as if the two superviews that contain the current view are also dismissed. Is that what this command will do, remove all viewControllers?

Comment: A bit more detail. So I added the command you suggested, and my code now looks like this:

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
//[self.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view release];

Result: when I click the "done" button once, nothing seems to happen. Twice, still nothing. Then, on the third click, the current stats view dissolves, and the app screen goes totally white, as if every view controller in the app has been dismissed.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Regarding these three clicks: it's almost as if on the first click, the bottom-most view controller is dimissed, then on the second click, the middle one, and then on the final click of the button, the topmost view controller is dismissed, and once it disappears, there's no view controller left to display. Could that actually be occurring? Very odd! Any thoughts? Thx!

Comment: DCGod, I added your line of code, then uncommented my other two lines in my MainGameViewController, and now the "done" button on the stats page works on the first click, but the main problem still remains: the  "parent"/super view that hosted that view still remains, but when it runs on the iPhone, that gameplay view underneath is elegantly removed no problem -- but on the iPad, that gameplay view still remains visible. Thanks for any other suggestions, and thank you for your original comment, it added a nice dissolve, even if it didn't solve the main issue! :)